# EF Core: change column to be identity after it is created

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a already existing db with a non identity column. I change the id property to be like this.

```cs
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public long Id { get; set; }
```

but when I run `dotnet ef migrations add` migration looks like this.

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    
}
```

Isn't there a way of doing this with ef core?

Comment: Have you checked database? Probably EF Core made `Id` as Identity automatically by convention. So adding additional attribute do not change anything. Check `{ContextName}tSnapshot.cs` file for `SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns`

Comment: Thanks, ef core snapshot has that line but in MSSMS the columns `Is Identity` is false, so I'm gonna need to manually update the db I guess